# Function with maybe output

Tags: haskell

I have a function which outputs a type of `Maybe Value` but I just want the value for the type `Value` for the specific case that I know that it will produce a value, however, when I try to use that just as `value` I get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Value' with 'Maybe Value'.
```

Comment: you can use `Data.Maybe.fromJust` or just use a pattern `let (Just value) = ...` if you are really sure

Comment: Can you present your code example?

Comment: Rather than assume you have a `Just` value, use the `Functor` or `Monad` instance to work with the value.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use partial functions such as `fromJust`. There are many safe options, which guarantee your program will not crash, in all cases.

Suppose that `m :: Maybe Int` and we want to add one to the integer, or return `1` if there is no integer (`m = Nothing`). We can use:

- explicit pattern matching (the most basic way)

  ```
  case m of
    Nothing -> 1
    Just x  -> x+1
  ```
- the `maybe` function (a compact form of pattern matching)

  ```
  maybe 1 (\x -> x+1) m
  ```
- the `fromMaybe` function

  ```
  -- if m == Nothing, return 0, then add 1
  fromMaybe 0 m + 1
  ```

If instead we want to return `Just (x+1)`, and keep `Nothing` as it is:

- `fmap (+1) m`
- monadic combinators (often overkill, but convenient in some complex cases)

  ```
  do x <- m ; return (x+1)
  [ x+1 | x <- m ]  -- with MonadComprehensions
  ```
- applicative/alternative combinators

---

Note that there *are* some cases where partial projections are better than safe alternatives. For instance, if there's no sensible value to map `Nothing` to, because `Nothing` should never, ever occur, crashing the program is arguably a better option than returning a wrong dummy value. Indeed, silently ignoring the `Nothing` bug, and returning a plausible result may cause big headaches during debugging. In such cases, "crash early" is the right thing to do.

Use your wisdom to evaluate whether you are in one such case. Even then, an explicit `error "foo: internal error -- found Nothing!"` will provide a better, more specific runtime error message than a generic `fromJust: Nothing` error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are 100% sure that there is a value, you can use [`fromJust`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromJust) to retrieve it. However it will error if you call it on `Nothing`.

Comment: I would typically, personally recommend using `let Just x = ... in ...` over `fromJust`, given the choice between those two. If `fromJust` fails, the error doesn't have a line number while the `let ... in ...` version would give a line number in its error message.